# php short tags not working in os x

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard

I've stumbled upon a strange problem. I made a regular os x system update (my os is Snow Leopard) and since then something strange happened to PHP. Now the short tags don't work anymore even though are enabled in the `php.ini` file. phpMyAdmin refuses to log me in. I cannot see the databases I had created even if I connect to MySQL through the terminal. Good thing is though that my still websites run perfectly.

Comment: You could do a `phpinfo()` to see whether the change took effect. But... if phpMyAdmin works, but doesn't log you in, that has nothing to do with short open tags, does it?

Comment: There apparently is something more happening than just short tags being disabled. For start check what `phpinfo()` displays (you should see short tags status there among other things)

Comment: of course, another option would be to stop using a (long-time) deprecated delimiter for your PHP code

Comment: @HorusKol: Can you provide a page in documentation which says short tags are deprecated?

Comment: in my php.ini the short tags are set to On but wher I run phpinfo() it shows it's Off!!! Why is that?? I'm confused!

Comment: Mauro74: 1. in phpinfo() check which `php.ini` file is being used. 2. You did restart your server after editing php.ini, didn't you?

Comment: Did you try restarting any web services/rebooting/etc?  Sounds dumb, but it's happened to me before.

Comment: @Mchl - I'm sorry, you're right - I was overstating it. However, they "are not recommended" as they are not universally enabled: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php - so I consider them to be as good as deprecated.

Comment: @HorusKol:I would love to see them deprecated and eventually removed too, but this time has not yet come. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify easily whether the short tags actually work from the command-line.

```
$ php
<? phpinfo(); ?>
^D
```

My Apple-provided PHP obeys the short_open_tag = On -setting in the /etc/php.ini fine. Your database issues are not related to this, since they persist even with the MySQL command line.

Answer (score 2):

To fix on Lion, go and edit the file `/etc/php.ini` , search the line `short_open_tag = Off` and replace it with `short_open_tag = On` , then restart apache (from command line this can be done by root by typing `apachectl restart`). This worked for me.

Comment: You can use `sudo apachectl restart` if you aren't root